# remove last word continuously and check in database table java

Tags: java, mysql

i have a small translation program to develop. The user input a sentence and the sentence is then check in a table in my database. if the sentence to sentence match is found. it displays the result else it removes the last word of the sentence and rechecks until a match is found or until one word is left( to be developed) . i have a small implementation for the handling of sentence to sentence match but i am having a small problem with my loop. i cannot figure out out to make it work. I know the problem is the the else part of loop i cannot figure out how to do it. I am not sure if the compiler will even loop back for the truncated sentence.

```
                 String sentence = "i am a good boy";
                 for(int j=0;j<sentence.length();j++)
                 {          

                    if(sentence.length()>1)
                    {
                        sentence = lookUpSentencePart(sentence);      
                        rs2 = sentenceDBQuery(sentence,srcLanguage,targLanguage);

                        if(rs2.first()==true)
                        {

                            System.out.println("mon pass dan rs1 true");
                            sb1.append(rs1.getString(targLanguage));
                            sentencePart = sb1.toString();
                            System.out.println(sentencePart);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sentence = lookUpSentencePart(sentence);
                            rs2 = sentenceDBQuery(sentence,srcLanguage,targLanguage);
                            if(rs2.first()==true)
                            {
                                sb1.append(rs1.getString(targLanguage));
                                sentencePart = sb1.toString();
                                System.out.println(sentencePart);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
public String lookUpSentencePart(String sentence)
{
    sentence = sentence.substring(0, sentence.lastIndexOf(" "));
    return sentence;
}
public ResultSet sentenceDBQuery(String sentence, String source, String target)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt;
    myConnection db = new myConnection();
    try
    {
        Connection myConn = db.theconnect();
        stmt = myConn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT " + target + " from sentence WHERE " + source + " = '" + sentence+"'");
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Please be more specific.

Comment: @shmosel i am unsure if the compiler will even go through and reloop the updated sentence :/

Comment: The compiler compiles your code, the runtime runs it. Does your code compile or not? Does it do what you want? How can you be "unsure"? What do you want it to do? What is it doing? How do you expect us to help you if you can't define the problem?

Comment: runtime calculates number of for loop executions only once before starting executing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need smth like that :) You still need to add some boundary checks

```
String[] sentence = "i am a good boy".split(" ");
for(int j=0;j<sentence.length;j++)
{
    String realSentence = buildSentence(sentence, j);      
    rs2 = sentenceDBQuery(realSentence,srcLanguage,targLanguage);

    if(rs2.first()==true)
    {

        System.out.println("mon pass dan rs1 true");
        sb1.append(rs1.getString(targLanguage));
        sentencePart = sb1.toString();
        System.out.println(sentencePart);
    }
}

public String buildSentence(String[] parts, int index) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < (parts.length - index); j++) {
        sb.append(parts[j]).append(" ");
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    return result.toString();
}
```